# Why can't I find "hadoop map/reduce" after I put "hadoop-eclipse-plugin-2.5.2.jar" in /eclipse/plugins?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I have already installed hadoop-2.5.2 and eclipse neon.1a in Win10 system, but after I put  "hadoop-eclipse-plugin-2.5.2.jar" in /eclipse/plugins, I can't find "hadoop map/reduce" after I click "windows" and "preferences" in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just "drop in" a new plug-in, put it in the `eclipse/dropins` folder. Otherwise, you're expected to install it properly using P2, or at least launch Eclipse with the `-clean` command line argument.

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake that I put it in the wrong folder `plugins` , I have installed it successfully with your attention just now! Thanks again!